# A Vandermonde-type matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, determinant, singularity

This is most certainly known, but I was unable to find a reference.

For a polynomial $P$ over a field $\mathbb F$ and a set $\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ of field elements, consider the matrix
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix}
     P(a_1) & P(a_2) & \dotsb & P(a_n) \\
     P'(a_1) & P'(a_2) & \dotsb & P'(a_n) \\
       & & \vdots \\
     P^{(n-1)}(a_1) & P^{(n-1)}(a_2) & \dotsb & P^{(n-1)}(a_n)
   \end{pmatrix} $$
where $P^{(k)}$ are the formal derivatives of $P$. When is this matrix non-singular?

Comment: So for characteristic zero, you think it suffices to have ${\rm deg}(P)=-1$?

Comment: This determinant cannot be called a Vandermonde matrix ; see the definition of such a matrix which deals with successive powers of second line entries.

Comment: I am concerned about the case $n=1$, $P(X)=X$, $a_1=0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I do not call it a Vandermonde matrix, but a *Vandermonde-type* matrix, which I think is very reasonable. In fact, this is a generalization of the Vandermonde matrix (take $P(x)=x^n$).

Comment: I don't agree, if you take $P(x)=x^n$, you have spurious coefficients $n$, then $n(n-1)$, etc.

Comment: @JeanMarie, when $n<p$ we could insert the factorials without loss.

Comment: I am finding it hard to believe there's a simple criterion. Maybe it might be worth considering first the case where the $a_i$ are not roots of $P$? [I've been looking at pathological cases like each of $a_1,\dots, a_k$ is a $k$-fold root of $P$, when singularity is guaranteed if $n<2k$].

Comment: @ancientmathematician: you may well be right, particularly taking into account that *any* function over a finite field is a polynomial. Still, I hope that there may exist a reasonable sufficient condition for low-degree polynomials. Also, it is difficult for me to believe that this problem has never been considered before.

Comment: Are you interested mainly/only by the case where $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field ? The notation $\mathbb{F}$ invites the reader to think so (but you don't say it explicitly) because, when one considers real or complex fields, one uses usually $\mathbb{K}$ (K = körper, name for the field structure in german, similar to "corps" in French).

Comment: @JeanMarie: You are right about the finite fields. Anyway, I was able to settle the special case I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** an answer, just a long comment.

If there is no easy answer then I suggest that you need to generalise a bit before you look for an answer in the literature. My first suggestion is that (for a moment) you make replace the $a_i$ by a set of independent transcendentals $x_1,x_2, \dots$. Let $y_1,y_2,\dots$ be another such, and then let $P(X):=\prod_1^{m}(X-y_i)$ so that $P(X)=\sum_{0}^{m}f_i (-1)^{n-i}X^i$, say.

Consider now the function
$$
\frac{\left|\begin{matrix}
     P(x_1) & P(x_2) & \dotsb & P(x_n) \\
     P'(x_1) & P'(x_2) & \dotsb & P'(x_n) \\
       & & \vdots \\
     P^{(n-1)}(x_1) & P^{(n-1)}(x_2) & \dotsb & P^{(n-1)}(x_n)
   \end{matrix}\right|}{\Delta(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)}
$$
where $\Delta(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$ is the usual Vandermonde determinant. This is a symmetric function, and it seems a natural question to ask whether we can express it explicitly in terms of $P$ and some natural basis of the symmetric functions: perhaps there is an answer in one of the standard books, but I don't know enough to tell.

If one were very bold one could ask whether this function is recognisable:

$$
\frac{\left|\begin{matrix}
     P^{(r_1)}(x_1) & P^{(r_1)}(x_2) & \dotsb & P^{(r_1)}(x_n) \\
     P^{(r_2)}(x_1) & P^{(r_2)}(x_2) & \dotsb & P^{(r_2)}(x_n) \\
       & & \vdots \\
     P^{(r_n)}(x_1) & P^{(r_n)}(x_2) & \dotsb & P^{(r_n)}(x_n)
   \end{matrix}\right|}{\Delta(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for sharing the thoughts, I will try to check this direction.